# Get the middle/center pixel of a segmentation

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a segmented image. I wish to extract the middle pixel(s) of each segmentation. The goal is to extract the mean color from the middle pixel.

The following diagram illustrates what I mean by 'middle pixel':
[image]

The `alternative middle pixels` are also acceptable.

What algorithms/functions are available in `Matlab` to achieve something similar to this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm understanding what you want correctly, you're looking for the **centroid**.  MATLAB has the [`regionprops`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html) function which measures the properties of separate binary objects as long as the objects.

You can use the `Centroid` property.  Assuming your image is stored in `im` and is binary, something like this will do:

```
out = regionprops(im, 'Centroid');
```

The output will be a structure array of `N` elements where `N` corresponds to the total number of objects found in the image.  To access the i<sup>th</sup> object's centroid, simply do:

```
cen = out(i).Centroid;
```

If you wish to collect all centroids and place them perhaps in a `N x 2` numeric array, something like this would work:

```
out = reshape([out.Centroid], 2, []).';
```

Each row would be the centroid of an object found in the image.  Take note that an object is considered to be a blob of white pixels that are connected to each other.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My segmentation is currently stored in a `1x3 cell `. Any idea how to convert this to a binary image?

Comment: I ran `regionprops` using the cell array and got this http://i.imgur.com/EweiqAZ.png .Does this mean that this many segments were found in the image? Or is this incorrect as I used an array cell rather than a binary object.

Comment: I can't say more until you actually show me what the original cell array contents are. This was unclear from the beginning and that lack of information didn't help me in answering your question. I went with my best guess. Is it possible for you to somewhere upload or show me what the cell array contents look like?

Comment: I was reading about `centroids` in my initial search and I think your interpretation was correct. Let me explain a little more in detail. I have an image, on which I am performing color-based segmentation using K-Means clustering. My code looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/qfXD4D1.png. (The cell array I'm referring to is at the very end of the code) My objective is to look at the different segments in the image and identify the color towards the center of the segment. If the center is close to white colored, I want to pick those segments out. If the middle is the same, I want to confirm it.

Comment: @john Wait a minute. You're using `kmeans`? It already *gives* you the centroids of the clusters.

Comment: @beaker is correct. Using kmeans already gives you the centres. I'm not sure what your question is now.

Comment: Well I followed this process from the docs http://mathworks.com/help/images/examples/color-based-segmentation-using-k-means-clustering.html , I'm not sure how to access the centroids you're taking about.

Comment: Also, the resulting variable of the segmentation is a `uint8`. This is different from the `array cell` I mentioned in my previous comments.

Comment: @john In [Step 3](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/color-based-segmentation-using-k-means-clustering.html#zmw57dd0e2708) of the example you linked, the call to `kmeans` returns `[cluster_idx, cluster_center]`. `cluster_center` is the list of centroids. See [kmeans](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html).

Comment: Thanks, after running the code my `cluster_center` looks like this http://i.imgur.com/gN0woTd.png can you explain what this is? Are these the coordinates to 2 identified centroids?

Comment: What do you expect them to be? What do they look like to you? What does the documentation say they are?